# Why TLnetcomponent Socket Disconnect event won't trigger?

Tags: sockets, events, connection, lazarus

I have a TLNetcomponent on my form and I have a disconnect procedure for onDisconnect event, but it won't fire or trigger when TLNETcomponent disconnects. Why?

Comment: Do you use a connection oriented protocol ?

Comment: Yes, I do for the communication.